# Кнопка с градиентом

Tags: android, android-drawable

Пытаюсь сделать вот такую кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь это сделать подобным образом, что  то типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
    >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff297baf"
                android:endColor="#ff16c0e3"
                android:type="linear"
                android:angle="0"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <solid
                android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

т.е. я пытаюсь сделать одну фигуру градиентом и внутри нее еще одну фигуру просто белую с отступами но вижу либо один градиент либо только белое, пробовал отступы и там и там ставить.В чем может быть проблема? Как сделать вложенные фигуры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем то у меня проблема не воспроизводится.

вот разметка:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp">
            </corners>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#634b25"
                android:endColor="#96743e"
                android:centerColor="#e4dbce" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp">
            </corners>
            <solid
                android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

вот результат:

[image: scrn]

я только убрал атрибуты, дублирующие дефолтные и все в основном. Еще градиент от центра.

Comment: Отлично, я  подобным образом пробовал делать, но не запуская проект, видать в превью отображается несколько иначе!

Comment: @KirillStoianov После внесения изменений в разметку нужно делать Make (или даже Rebuild иногда) проекта, чтобы изменения корректно отобразились в превью студии, иначе там быстро образуется какой то хаос.